# user likes in a RESTful API

Tags: rest

how do you handle a user 'liking' a post or object in a RESTful API so that they can only like it once?  Do you create a many to many relationship and create an endpoint to check if a user liked the object for each object that you load?  This seems very request intensive and I'm wondering if there is a better, established solution?

Comment: Just add the userId to the list of users that has liked it  and every time he likes it ,since his name is already added it will not increment.

Comment: so you'd do something like a many to many relationship that keeps a table with columns 'post id' and 'user id'?

Comment: i think its a one to many, one post many likes(users).

Comment: do you think if i have this type of relationship it'd be worth it to use mongodb or will postgres be adequate?

Comment: the database is immaterial, at the end your design is what it counts. So choose whichever you are comfortable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the users must be authenticated to perform the request and the request contain all the details to be properly authenticated, you could consider the following approach:

- `POST /posts/:postid/likes`: Records a like for the user in post with the given id.
- `GET /posts/:postid/likes`: Returns a representation of all likes for the post with the given id.
- `DELETE /posts/:postid/likes/:userid`: Deletes a like for the user in the post with the given id.

Comment: Would the `DELETE` delete *all* likes for the post?

Comment: @LutzHorn Good spot. The `/posts/:id/likes` URI identifies the collection of likes of a particular post. A `DELETE` operation in that URI expresses a delete operation over the whole collection. A user identifier could be introduced to identify a single like in the collection.

Comment: If an authorization header is set, there will be no need for the user identifier for the delete and post request.